# 2 SharePoint sites in a site collection responding to the same code differently

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a c# app to download files from a SharePoint 2010 directory (file list I believe is the proper term for sharepoint but I have only picked that up and am not 100% sure.  can some one confirm I have the right terminology?)

I have the following code which works for one site using `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client`:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sourcePath.Site);
Web web = context.Web;
Folder spfolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sourcePath.Folder);
FileCollection files = spfolder.Files;

context.Load(context.Web);
context.Load(spfolder);
context.Load(files);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (File file in files)
{
    destfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(move.FileDest, file.Name);
    FileInformation f = File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, file.ServerRelativeUrl);

    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(destfile, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        f.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

The issue is that on site one (http://server/sites/department1/site1) `files` shows the files in the enumeration and copies them just fine.  site two ((http://server/sites/department2/site2) the files enumeration is empty (and since its empty no files are downloaded)

The weird part is when I look at `spfolder` for site 2 the `ItemCount` is correct (5, one sub folder and 4 files) so I am unsure what is going on.

For permissions I have read only on the site one where the code works and Full Control on the site two where the code will not work.

As an aside one of the other developers showed me UNC pathing to the sharepoint directory (`\\site\folder`) which works but is much slower than the CSOM access.  I would still prefer to get the SharePoint code working though.

EDIT:  My terminology was slightly off, they are not different websites but 2 different sites in the same site collection

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you come up with a solution? If so, could you post it?

Comment: @dotnetN00b unfortunatly I have not found a solution yet.  I am still working on it in my spare time.  After I found I could access the "folders" with a UNC path (not sure how that is configured but it works) I moved on until it became a blocker.  I will update if I figure out what is going on as the UNC access is much slower for the site I can access with CSOM

Comment: If you could share that code, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @dotnetN00b the unc path is a sharepoint 2007 + feature and a im sure some googling will yeild the answer to enable it.  I am just a dev and not a sharepoint admin.

Answer (score 1):

can you provide sourcePath.Site and sourcePath.Folder values for both sites?

As you have full access, the fault will not be in insufficient rights (missing Browse Directories). I suppose the problem will be that one site is on own domain and other is located within site/SiteName. But it is just a guess.

make sure that sourcePath.Folder is formatted as follows:

```
/[web]/[libraryName]/[folder]
```

or

```
[libraryName]/[folder]
```

Comment: Its 2 sub sites in a site collection (same root server).  After playing around with the URL's to the folders I was able to come up with the proper paths.  Like the question states, I can get the meta information back for the folder in site 2 that I am trying to query.